# In AngularJS or html or Javascript, need to add <td> cells to a table based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dropdown

I have a dropdown box:

```
 <select ng-model="numberselected">    
   <option value="">Select One</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
```

I have a table:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>row </td>
     <td><input></input></td> 
   </tr>                   
 </table>
```

I need as many

```
 <td><input></input></td>
```

as the user selected in the dropdown. How can I do this in AngularJs? Or html? or javascript?

Comment: Great! That works! It's just what I was looking for! A further question. I want to have exactly the same number of <td> in the table row as what is selected in the drop down box. I am guessing I would have to delete <td> as well if the new selection is less than the old selection. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the insertCell, for doing this you have to get the row in wich you want to add the `td`

```js
const SelectedVal = (e)=>{
    let element = document.getElementById('row')
    let i = parseInt(e.value)
  let numberTd = [...element.childNodes].filter(el=>{return el.tagName == 'TD'}).length
  
  for(let z = 0;z<numberTd;z++){
     element.deleteCell(0)
  }
  
  for(let x = 0;x<i;x++){
  var tdAdded = element.insertCell(0);
  tdAdded.innerHTML = "New cell";
  }
}
```

```html
 <table>
   <tr id="row">
     <td>row </td>
   </tr>                   
 </table> 
 
  <select onchange="SelectedVal(this)" >    
   <option value="">Select One</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Great! That works! It's just what I was looking for! A further question. I want to have exactly the same number of <td> in the table row as what is selected in the drop down box. I am guessing I would have to delete <td> as well if the new selection is less than the old selection. How would I do this?

Comment: I'm updating my answer in order to achieve that.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the update! That works great!